# py2app problems, getting errors

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I'm trying to test out the functionality of py2app, for creating standalone mac applications. I generated a setup file for my test code, called 'hello.py'.

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['hello.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
   app=APP,
   data_files=DATA_FILES,
   options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
   setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And I'm trying to make a simple app that just says hello world with a GUI. Here is the code for hello.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QLabel("Hello World")
widget.show()


app.exec_()
```

The script above runs just fine, but when I try to use py2app, I get some errors. When I run 'python setup.py py2app'

```
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named py2app-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Sphinx-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named decorator-4
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named altgraph-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named matplotlib-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named alabaster-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named modulegraph-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Jinja2-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named jedi-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pickleshare-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named macholib-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Babel-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named sphinx_rtd_theme-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pip-7
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named wheel-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named python_dateutil-2
```

After these errors, it py2app seems to be running as it normally should, but of course the app itself does not work. What is going on here? How do I fix this?

Here is the final line of the Terminal output as well.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
setup_requires=['py2app'],
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in          setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in   run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in   run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site- packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 659, in run
self._run()
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 865, in _run
self.run_normal()
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 959, in run_normal
self.create_binaries(py_files, pkgdirs, extensions, loader_files)
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1214, in create_binaries
platfiles = mm.run()
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site- packages/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 105, in run
mm.run_file(fn)
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 84, in run_file
self.scan_node(m)
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 110, in scan_node
m = self.load_file(filename, caller=node)
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 93, in load_file
newname = self.locate(name, loader=caller)
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOStandalone.py", line 23, in locate
newname = super(FilteredMachOGraph, self).locate(filename, loader)
File "/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py", line 49, in locate
loader=loader.filename)
TypeError: dyld_find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loader'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small hack that will work for this problem,

1. Go to your path `/Users/Apollo/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py` and open this file.
2. On line 49, change `loader=loader.filename` to `loader_path=loader.filename`

Run the setup.py again.

Comment: @sidpat I am getting the same errors: `ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named`. I modified `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/macholib/MachOGraph.py`.

Comment: any update on this? this only creates a nasty syntax error for me. BTW I am using Python 3.6.1, MAC OSX Sierra 10.12.4, py2app version 0.13. error code upon py2app'ing https://pastebin.com/e2V5vRVn @sidpat