# There is something wrong with my building app with py2app

Tags: macos, python-2.7, py2app

It works well with `$ python setup.py py2app -A`, but not with `$ python setup.py py2app`. What should I do to solve the problem? Could you help me?

The following is what's in my terminal:

```
(/Users/zhaotong/anaconda) zhaotongdeMacBook-Pro-2:function zhaotong$ python setup.py py2app
running py2app
creating /Users/zhaotong/Desktop/function/build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/zhaotong/Desktop/function/build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/zhaotong/Desktop/function/build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
*** using recipe: subprocess ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
*** using recipe: virtualenv ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
*** using recipe: importlib ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
*** using recipe: re ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe wx ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
*** using recipe: ftplib ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe wx ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
*** using recipe: mimetypes ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe wx ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
--- Skipping recipe qt5 ---
--- Skipping recipe pyopengl ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
*** using recipe: os_module ***
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe wx ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
--- Skipping recipe qt5 ---
--- Skipping recipe pyopengl ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
sip: packages: set(['cloudpickle', 'chardet-2.3.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'service_identity', 'Markdown-2.2.0.dist-info', 'pydispatch', 'flask', 'blaze', 'sympy', 'zmq', 'pep8-1.7.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'markupsafe', 'bleach', 'pyximport', 'bottleneck', 'pbr', 'py2app', 'httpagentparser-1.7.9.dist-info', 'anaconda_navigator', 'PyQt4.QtTest', 'bleach-1.5.0.dist-info', 'jsonschema', 'odo', 'click', 'mpl_toolkits', 'py-1.4.32-py2.7.egg-info', 'cffi-1.9.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'ptyprocess', 'configparser-3.5.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'spyder_pylint', 'jedi', 'altgraph', 'itchat', 'matplotlib', 'wcwidth', 'anaconda_navigator-1.2.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'Scrapy-1.3.2.dist-info', 'traitlets', 'cssselect', 'terminado', 'PyQt4.Qt', 'snowballstemmer', 'pycparser', 'mistune-0.7.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'toolz', 'IPython', 'service_identity-16.0.0.dist-info', 'jieba-0.39.dist-info', 'patsy-0.4.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'wheel-0.29.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'virtualenv-15.1.0.dist-info', 'contextlib2-0.5.4-py2.7.egg-info', 'widgetsnbextension', 'jupyter_core', 'pylint', 'QtPy-1.2.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'wordcloud-1.3.1.dist-info', 'functools32', 'partd-0.3.7-py2.7.egg-info', 'cssselect-1.0.1.dist-info', 'locket', 'idna-2.2-py2.7.egg-info', 'spyder', 'SQLAlchemy-1.1.5-py2.7.egg-info', 'Sphinx-1.5.1-py2.7.egg', 'incremental', 'fastcache', 'PyQt4.QtHelp', 'lxml', 'chaco', 'pytest-3.0.5-py2.7.egg-info', 'OpenSSL', 'pygpu-0.6.4-py2.7.egg-info', 'pygame', 'attrs-16.3.0.dist-info', 'virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'datashape', 'mayavi', 'portend-2.1.2.dist-info', 'notebook', 'virtualenv_support', 'datashape-0.5.4-py2.7.egg-info', 'pygpu', 'pyface', 'astroid', 'spyder_breakpoints', 'nltk', 'dask-0.11.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'cffi', 'Automat-0.5.0.dist-info', 'envisage', 'multipledispatch-0.4.9-py2.7.egg-info', 'yaml', 'isort', 'tables-3.2.2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-info', 'xlwings', 'pypng-0.0.18.dist-info', 'jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'scipy', 'jinja2', 'automat', 'parsel-1.1.0.dist-info', 'alabaster-0.7.9-py2.7.egg-info', 'pathlib2-2.2.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'tvtk', 'Jinja2-2.9.4-py2.7.egg-info', 'h5py', 'funcsigs', 'clyent-1.2.2-py2.7.egg-info', 'pyqrcode', 'xlrd', 'tempora', 'spyder_io_dcm', 'reportlab', 'docutils', 'pygame-1.9.3.dist-info', 'qtconsole', 'anaconda_client-1.6.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'incremental-16.10.1.dist-info', 'wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.7.egg-info', 'modulegraph', 'nbformat', 'PyQt4.QtNetwork', 'backports.weakref-1.0rc1.dist-info', 'astropy', 'cycler-0.10.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'reportlab-3.4.0.dist-info', 'prompt_toolkit-1.0.9-py2.7.egg-info', 'llvmlite', 'mkl', 'h5py-2.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-info', 'et_xmlfile', 'gevent-1.2.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'xlrd-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'pexpect', 'twisted', 'bokeh', 'queuelib', 'astropy-1.0.4-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-info', 'xlsxwriter', 'altgraph-0.14.dist-info', 'conda_env', 'PyQt4', 'Flask-0.12-py2.7.egg-info', 'prompt_toolkit', 'pyqtgraph', 'wordcloud', 'chardet', 'plotly', 'ipykernel', 'bs4', 'sqlalchemy', 'tempora-1.8.dist-info', 'py2app-0.14.dist-info', 'PyQt4.QtXmlPatterns', 'mock-2.0.0.dist-info', 'nltk-3.2.2-py2.7.egg-info', 'babel', 'spyder_profiler', 'tensorflow-1.2.0.dist-info', 'html5lib', 'traitsui', 'chest', 'nbconvert', 'pyasn1_modules-0.0.8.dist-info', 'CherryPy-10.2.2.dist-info', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'tornado', 'kiva', 'colorama', 'mayavi-4.5.1.dev0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg', 'numba-0.26.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-info', 'PyQt4.QtOpenGL', 'QtAwesome-0.4.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'unicodecsv', 'cherrypy_cors-1.5.dist-info', 'theano', 'w3lib-1.17.0.dist-info', 'PyQt4.QtScriptTools', 'networkx', 'wrapt', 'matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-info', 'qtpy', 'cheroot-5.7.0.dist-info', 'xlwt', 'queuelib-1.4.2.dist-info', 'cryptography', 'alabaster', 'cheroot', 'enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg-info', 'PyQt4.QtScript', 'funcsigs-1.0.2-py2.7.egg-info', 'lazy_object_proxy', 'nose-1.3.7-py2.7.egg-info', 'bitarray', 'ipywidgets', 'PyQt4.QtSql', 'dateutil', 'PyQt4.QtDeclarative', 'PyDispatcher-2.0.5.dist-info', 'cytoolz', 'lazy_object_proxy-1.2.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg-info', 'modulegraph-0.15.dist-info', 'spyder_io_hdf5', 'conda', 'imagesize-0.7.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'Keras-2.0.5-py2.7.egg', 'wx', 'PyQt4..DS_Store', 'boto', 'tlz', 'wx-3.0-osx_cocoa', 'numpydoc', 'PyQt4.QtWebKit', 'requests', 'vtk', 'ruamel_yaml', 'backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'markdown', 'sockjs_tornado-1.0.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'Cython', 'pyasn1_modules', 'pygments', 'aeosa', 'py', 'Pillow-3.4.2-py2.7.egg-info', 'tensorflow', 'numpy', 'et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'enable', 'pytz', 'external', 'pyvtk', 'pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-info', 'pyOpenSSL-16.2.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'protobuf-3.2.0.dist-info', 'rope', 'dask', 'cryptography-1.7.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'statsmodels', 'cherrypy', 'numba', 'click-6.7-py2.7.egg-info', 'apptools', 'mako', 'partd', 'itchat-1.3.9.dist-info', 'jupyter_console', 'Theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'zope', 'wheel', 'sockjs', 'macholib-1.8.dist-info', 'wxPython-4.0.0a3.dist-info', 'jupyter_client', 'openpyxl-2.4.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'pyflakes', 'PyQt4.QtXml', 'macholib', 'astroid-1.4.9-py2.7.egg-info', 'numpydoc-0.6.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'Mako-1.0.6-py2.7.egg-info', 'numexpr', 'tables', 'PIL', 'decorator-4.0.11-py2.7.egg-info', 'bin', 'openpyxl', 'widgetsnbextension-1.2.6-py2.7.egg-info', 'blaze-0.10.1-py2.7.egg-info', 'constantly-15.1.0.dist-info', 'mpmath', 'nose', 'binstar_client', 'networkx-1.11-py2.7.egg-info', 'google', 'odo-0.5.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'apptools-4.4.0.dist-info', 'w3lib', 'traits', 'gevent', 'skimage', 'psutil', 'redis', 'backports', 'beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'werkzeug', 'ipython_genutils', 'qtawesome', 'requests-2.12.4-py2.7.egg-info', 'enum', 'Crypto', 'ply', 'MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7.egg-info', 'PyQt4.QtGui', 'PyQt4.QtDesigner', 'jieba', 'PyQt4.uic', 'pyasn1', 'jdcal-1.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'pyqtgraph-0.10.0.dist-info', 'PyQRCode-1.2.1.dist-info', 'pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.7.egg-info', 'llvmlite-0.11.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'numpy-1.13.1.dist-info', 'plotly-2.0.12.dist-info', 'constantly', 'toolz-0.8.2-py2.7.egg-info', 'Twisted-17.1.0.dist-info', 'appnope', 'Werkzeug-0.11.15-py2.7.egg-info', 'PyQt4.QtMultimedia', 'imagesize', 'PyQt4.phonon', 'pbr-2.0.0.dist-info', 'scikit_image-0.11.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'PyQt4.QtSvg', 'backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg-info', 'xlwt-1.2.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'Bottleneck-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'attr', 'python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'argcomplete-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'httpagentparser', 'Babel-2.3.4-py2.7.egg-info', 'sklearn', 'dill', 'argcomplete', 'flask_cors', 'parsel', 'pip', 'curl', '_pytest', 'patsy', 'scrapy', 'Flask_Cors-3.0.2-py2.7.egg-info', 'html5lib-0.9999999.dist-info', 'pandas', 'mock', 'clyent', 'singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'multipledispatch', 'Pygments-2.1.3-py2.7.egg-info', 'concurrent', 'PyVTK-0.5.18.dist-info', 'seaborn', 'idna', 'zope.interface-4.3.3.dist-info'])
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named chardet-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Markdown-2
.......
.......
File "/Users/zhaotong/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1072, in _determine_parent
parent = self.findNode(pname)
File "/Users/zhaotong/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 967, in findNode
data = super(ModuleGraph, self).findNode(name)
File "/Users/zhaotong/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py", line 141, in findNode
ident = self.getRawIdent(node)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Check this out - [py2app-problems-getting-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136313/py2app-problems-getting-errors)