# Why do I receive 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded' when compiling with py2app?

Tags: python, py2app

I am trying to turn my python program into a stand-alone app on my Mac (10.14.6) using the latest version of py2app. Every time I do, I receive a many errors saying that files could not be imported (see below) and it ends with the 'maximum recursion depth exceeded message.'

To ensure that it had nothing to do with my program, I wrote a simple Python program that contains only a print statement and the results are the same.

Any idea why this is occurring?

See the output below (greatly shortened because of the character limit:

```
python setup.py py2app
running py2app
creating /Users/aamador/Desktop/build
creating /Users/aamador/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64
creating /Users/aamador/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.7-standalone
creating /Users/aamador/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/aamador/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/aamador/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.7-standalone/app/temp
creating /Users/aamador/Desktop/dist
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
CTYPES USERS []
--- Skipping recipe ctypes ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
*** using recipe: ftplib *** {}
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
CTYPES USERS []
--- Skipping recipe ctypes ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
*** using recipe: importlib *** {'expected_missing_imports': {'_frozen_importlib_external'}}
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
CTYPES USERS []
--- Skipping recipe ctypes ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
*** using recipe: mimetypes *** {'expected_missing_imports': {'winreg'}}
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
CTYPES USERS []
--- Skipping recipe ctypes ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
*** using recipe: os_module *** {'expected_missing_imports': {'nt'}}
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
CTYPES USERS []
--- Skipping recipe ctypes ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
*** using recipe: pydoc *** {}
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
CTYPES USERS []
--- Skipping recipe ctypes ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyenchant ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe pyopengl ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside2 ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
--- Skipping recipe qt5 ---
*** using recipe: re *** {'expected_missing_imports': {'sys.getwindowsversion'}}
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
CTYPES USERS []
--- Skipping recipe ctypes ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyenchant ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe pyopengl ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside2 ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
--- Skipping recipe qt5 ---
--- Skipping recipe scipy ---
*** using recipe: setuptools *** {'expected_missing_imports': {'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing', 'pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs', '__builtin__', '__main__.__requires__', 'pkg_resources.extern.six'}}
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
CTYPES USERS [SourceModule('ctypes._endian', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/_endian.py'), SourceModule('uuid', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/uuid.py'), Package('ctypes.macholib', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/macholib/__init__.py', ['/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/macholib']), SourceModule('ctypes._aix', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/_aix.py'), SourceModule('ctypes.util', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/util.py'), SourceModule('pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/appdirs.py')]
*** using recipe: ctypes *** {'prescripts': ['py2app.bootstrap.ctypes_setup']}
--- Skipping recipe PIL ---
--- Skipping recipe botocore ---
--- Skipping recipe docutils ---
--- Skipping recipe lxml ---
--- Skipping recipe matplotlib ---
--- Skipping recipe numpy ---
--- Skipping recipe pyenchant ---
--- Skipping recipe pygame ---
--- Skipping recipe pyopengl ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside ---
--- Skipping recipe pyside2 ---
--- Skipping recipe pyzmq ---
--- Skipping recipe qt5 ---
--- Skipping recipe scipy ---
--- Skipping recipe shiboken2 ---
sip: packages: {'Pygments-2.4.2.dist-info', 'seaborn-0.9.0.dist-info', 'nbconvert-5.6.0.dist-info', 'glob2', 'rope-0.14.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'wcwidth', 'jupyterlab_server-1.0.6.dist-info', 'toolz-0.10.0.dist-info', 'pandocfilters-1.4.2.dist-info', 'bs4', 'future-0.17.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'fsspec', 'PyQt5.pyrcc', 'keyring-18.0.0.dist-info', 'Flask-1.1.1.dist-info', 'et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'sortedcontainers', 'packaging', 'bitarray-1.0.1.dist-info', 'Sphinx-2.2.0.dist-info', 'mccabe-0.6.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'pkg_resources', 'bleach-3.1.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'dask-2.5.0.dist-info', 'openpyxl', 'Bottleneck-1.2.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'unicodecsv-0.14.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'idna', 'macholib', 'pluggy-0.13.0.dist-info', 'distributed-2.5.1.dist-info', 'sqlalchemy', 'send2trash', 'jdcal-1.4.1.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtMacExtras', 'zict', 'sklearn', 'appnope', 'tqdm', 'testpath-0.4.2.dist-info', 'xlwt-1.3.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'html5lib-1.0.1.dist-info', 'pyximport', 'attr', 'cytoolz', 'IPython', 'PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets', 'pygments', 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets', 'modulegraph-0.17.dist-info', 'jupyterlab-1.1.4-py3.7.egg-info', 'jupyter_console-6.0.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'backports.os-0.1.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'mkl_fft', 'scipy', 'backports', 'sphinx', 'mkl_service-2.3.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'Jinja2-2.10.1.dist-info', 'matplotlib', 'PyQt5.uic', 'pytest_openfiles-0.4.0.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtDesigner', 'test_data', 'joblib-0.13.2-py3.7.egg-info', 'Click-7.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'pyflakes-2.1.1.dist-info', 'pytest_doctestplus-0.4.0.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtLocation', 'beautifulsoup4-4.8.0.dist-info', 'sortedcollections', 'PyQt5.QtWebEngine', 'greenlet-0.4.15.dist-info', 'cytoolz-0.10.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'statsmodels-0.10.1.dist-info', 'xlsxwriter', 'ipython_genutils', 'sortedcollections-1.1.2.dist-info', 'mock-3.0.5.dist-info', 'gevent-1.4.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'lazy_object_proxy-1.4.2.dist-info', 'zict-1.0.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'certifi-2019.9.11-py3.7.egg-info', 'importlib_metadata-0.23.dist-info', 'pickleshare-0.7.5-py3.7.egg-info', 'widgetsnbextension', 'Pillow-6.1.0.dist-info', 'atomicwrites-1.3.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'pip-19.2.3-py3.7.egg-info', 'qtconsole', 'matplotlib-3.1.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'ipykernel-5.1.2.dist-info', 'MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info', 'decorator-4.4.0.dist-info', 'PyWavelets-1.0.3.dist-info', 'conda_package_handling-1.6.0.dist-info', 'jupyter_core-4.5.0.dist-info', 'pkginfo-1.5.0.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'tblib-1.4.0.dist-info', 'numexpr', 'sphinxcontrib_serializinghtml-1.1.3.dist-info', 'patsy', 'pytest_astropy-0.5.0.dist-info', 'colorama', 'PyQt5.QtPositioning', 'astroid-2.3.1.dist-info', 'libarchive', 'Cython-0.29.13.dist-info', 'flask', 'statsmodels', 'mpl_toolkits', 'jupyterlab_server', 'pytest_openfiles', 'ptyprocess', 'jinja2', 'gevent', 'tests', 'webencodings-0.5.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'ply-3.11-py3.7.egg-info', 'terminado', 'PyQt5.QtNetwork', 'partd-1.0.0.dist-info', 'jsonschema-3.0.2.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtDBus', 'webencodings', 'py2app', 'multipledispatch', 'XlsxWriter-1.2.1.dist-info', 'skimage', 'openpyxl-3.0.0.dist-info', 'cloudpickle-1.2.2.dist-info', 'navigator_updater-0.2.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'PyQt5.pylupdate', 'wcwidth-0.1.7-py3.7.egg-info', 'PyQt5.QtNfc', 'mistune-0.8.4.dist-info', 'anaconda_client-1.7.2-py3.7.egg-info', 'ipykernel', 'toolz', 'spyder_profiler', 'cffi', 'libfuturize', 'isort-4.3.21.dist-info', 'pexpect', 'pywt', 'numpy-1.17.2-py3.7.egg-info', 'asn1crypto', 'requests-2.22.0.dist-info', 'idna-2.8-py3.7.egg-info', 'nose', 'notebook', 'soupsieve', 'pylint-2.4.2.dist-info', 'keyring', 'PyQt5.QtOpenGL', 'prometheus_client', 'lxml', 'libpasteurize', 'pyOpenSSL-19.0.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'xlwings', 'pyzmq-18.1.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'numba', 'numba-0.45.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'mkl_fft-1.0.14-py3.7.egg-info', 'bottleneck', 'lazy_object_proxy', 'QtAwesome-0.6.0.dist-info', 'pytz', 'babel', 'xontrib', 'Send2Trash-1.5.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'OpenSSL', 'Babel-2.7.0.dist-info', 'past', 'conda-4.7.12-py3.7.egg-info', 'pandas-0.25.1.dist-info', 'fastcache', 'pytest_remotedata', 'tornado', 'pkginfo', 'PyQt5.QtGui', 'traitlets-4.3.2.dist-info', 'conda_verify-3.4.2.dist-info', 'fsspec-0.5.1.dist-info', 'scikit_image-0.15.0.dist-info', 'pip', 'singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py3.7.egg-info', 'modulegraph', 'simplegeneric-0.8.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'jedi', 'PyQt5.QtXmlPatterns', 'tables', 'itsdangerous', 'backcall', 'unicodecsv', 'backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0.dist-info', 'asn1crypto-0.24.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'pyrsistent', 'PyQt5.QtQml', 'cycler-0.10.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'backports.weakref-1.0.post1-py2.7.egg-info', 'soupsieve-1.9.3.dist-info', 'pandas', 'six-1.12.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'zmq', 'parso-0.5.1.dist-info', 'prometheus_client-0.7.1.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtSerialPort', 'QtPy-1.9.0.dist-info', 'astropy', 'h5py', 'mkl', 'PyQt5.QtXml', 'sphinxcontrib_jsmath-1.0.1.dist-info', 'jedi-0.15.1.dist-info', 'sphinxcontrib_websupport-1.1.2.dist-info', 'snowballstemmer', 'mock', 'nose-1.3.7-py3.7.egg-info', 'numexpr-2.7.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'pyrsistent-0.15.4.dist-info', 'astropy-3.2.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'setuptools', 'numpydoc-0.9.1.dist-info', 'jupyter_client', 'PyQt5.QtSensors', 'pexpect-4.7.0.dist-info', 'clyent-1.2.2-py3.7.egg-info', 'widgetsnbextension-3.5.1.dist-info', 'et_xmlfile', 'sphinxcontrib_htmlhelp-1.0.2.dist-info', 'chardet', 'importlib_metadata', 'PyQt5.Qt', 'sympy', 'macholib-1.11.dist-info', 'bokeh-1.3.4.dist-info', 'conda_verify', 'parso', 'Crypto', 'PySocks-1.7.1.dist-info', 'xlwt', 'more_itertools', 'urllib3', 'qtconsole-4.5.5.dist-info', 'bkcharts', 'backcall-0.1.0.dist-info', 'contextlib2-0.6.0.dist-info', 'pycparser', 'cffi-1.12.3.dist-info', 'rope', 'cryptography', 'Werkzeug-0.16.0.dist-info', 'spyder_kernels-0.5.2.dist-info', 'pluggy', 'wrapt', 'altgraph-0.16.1.dist-info', 'SQLAlchemy-1.3.8.dist-info', 'conda_build', 'seaborn', 'attrs-19.1.0.dist-info', 'ipywidgets-7.5.1.dist-info', 'pyodbc-4.0.27.dist-info', 'pylint', 'imagesize-1.1.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'testpath', 'json5', 'spyder_pylint', 'PyQt5.QtSvg', 'wurlitzer-1.0.3.dist-info', 'tqdm-4.36.1.dist-info', 'defusedxml', 'msgpack', 'distributed', 'docutils-0.15.2.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtWidgets', 'glob2-0.7.dist-info', 'bleach', 'tlz', 'jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore', 'ruamel_yaml', 'traitlets', 'jsonschema', 'networkx', 'jupyter_console', 'urllib3-1.24.2-py3.7.egg-info', 'isort', 'anaconda_project', 'yaml', 'kiwisolver-1.1.0.dist-info', 'docutils', 'scripts', 'backports.functools_lru_cache-1.5-py2.7.egg-info', 'numpy', 'bitarray', '_pytest', '__pycache__', 'qtpy', 'itsdangerous-1.1.0.dist-info', 'html5lib', 'ipywidgets', 'aeosa', 'xlrd', 'anaconda_navigator-1.9.7-py3.7.egg-info', 'binstar_client', 'cloudpickle', 'olefile', 'anaconda_project-0.8.3.dist-info', 'atomicwrites', 'PyQt5.QtWebChannel', 'lief-0.9.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'olefile-0.46-py3.7.egg-info', 'sphinxcontrib_devhelp-1.0.1.dist-info', 'scipy-1.3.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'prompt_toolkit-2.0.9.dist-info', 'path', 'sortedcontainers-2.1.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'altgraph', 'PyQt5.QtBluetooth', 'Cython', 'nltk', 'requests', 'certifi', 'llvmlite', 'conda', 'filelock-3.0.12.dist-info', 'scikit_learn-0.21.3.dist-info', 'sphinxcontrib', 'PyQt5.QtWebSockets', 'wheel-0.33.6-py3.7.egg-info', 'PyQt5.QtCore', 'pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg-info', 'alabaster-0.7.12.dist-info', 'py-1.8.0.dist-info', 'spyder_kernels', 'networkx-2.3.dist-info', 'clyent', 'joblib', 'PyQt5.QtQuick', 'navigator_updater', 'astroid', 'mkl_random', 'xlwings-0.15.10-py3.7.egg-info', 'mpmath', 'future', 'curl', 'pytest_arraydiff-0.3.dist-info', 'pytest_arraydiff', 'wrapt-1.11.2.dist-info', 'jupyterlab', 'dateutil', 'cryptography-2.7.dist-info', 'conda_package_handling', 'qtawesome', 'h5py-2.9.0.dist-info', 'pyflakes', 'spyder', 'boto', 'pytz-2019.2.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtTest', 'bokeh', 'sympy-1.4-py3.7.egg-info', 'sphinxcontrib_applehelp-1.0.1.dist-info', 'ipython-7.8.0.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtSql', 'anaconda_navigator', 'sphinxcontrib_qthelp-1.0.2.dist-info', 'prompt_toolkit', 'locket', 'conda_build-3.18.9-py3.7.egg-info', 'pathlib2-2.3.5.dist-info', 'dask', 'mkl_random-1.1.0.dist-info', 'spyder_breakpoints', 'click', 'defusedxml-0.6.0-py2.7.egg-info', 'pytest_remotedata-0.3.2.dist-info', 'psutil', 'conda_env', 'psutil-5.6.3.dist-info', 'jupyter_client-5.3.3.dist-info', 'spyder-3.3.6.dist-info', 'lief', 'markupsafe', 'pep8-1.7.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'PyQt5.__pycache__', 'nbformat', 'py', 'tornado-6.0.3.dist-info', 'zipp-0.6.0.dist-info', 'py2app-0.19.dist-info', 'bkcharts-0.2-py3.7.egg-info', 'chardet-3.0.4.dist-info', 'xlrd-1.2.0.dist-info', 'nbconvert', 'tables-3.5.2.dist-info', 'pytest-5.2.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'partd', 'snowballstemmer-1.9.1.dist-info', 'fastcache-1.1.0.dist-info', 'packaging-19.2.dist-info', 'HeapDict-1.0.1.dist-info', 'jupyter_core', 'PyQt5', 'imageio', 'alabaster', 'pyparsing-2.4.2.dist-info', 'nltk-3.4.5.dist-info', 'python_dateutil-2.8.0.dist-info', 'numpydoc', 'ply', 'libarchive_c-2.8-py3.7.egg-info', 'pathlib2', 'pytest_doctestplus', 'spyder_io_dcm', 'more_itertools-7.2.0.dist-info', 'PyQt5.QtPrintSupport', 'patsy-0.5.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'wheel', 'setuptools-41.2.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'json5-0.8.5.dist-info', 'pycodestyle-2.5.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'notebook-6.0.1.dist-info', 'backports.tempfile-1.0.dist-info', 'msgpack-0.6.1.dist-info', 'werkzeug', 'PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets', 'multipledispatch-0.6.0-py3.7.egg-info', 'nbformat-4.4.0.dist-info', 'lxml-4.4.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'spyder_io_hdf5', 'path.py-12.0.1.dist-info', 'tblib', 'colorama-0.4.1-py3.7.egg-info', 'PyQt5.QtHelp', 'PIL'}
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Pygments-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named seaborn-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named nbconvert-5
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named rope-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named jupyterlab_server-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named toolz-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pandocfilters-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named future-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named keyring-18
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Flask-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named et_xmlfile-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named bitarray-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Sphinx-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named mccabe-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named bleach-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named dask-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Bottleneck-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named unicodecsv-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pluggy-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named distributed-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named jdcal-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named testpath-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named xlwt-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named html5lib-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named modulegraph-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named jupyterlab-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named jupyter_console-6
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named mkl_service-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Jinja2-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pytest_openfiles-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named joblib-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Click-7
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pyflakes-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pytest_doctestplus-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named beautifulsoup4-4
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named greenlet-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named cytoolz-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named statsmodels-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named sortedcollections-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named mock-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named gevent-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named lazy_object_proxy-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named zict-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named certifi-2019
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named importlib_metadata-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pickleshare-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Pillow-6
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named atomicwrites-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pip-19
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named matplotlib-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named ipykernel-5
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named MarkupSafe-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named decorator-4
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named PyWavelets-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named conda_package_handling-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named jupyter_core-4
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pkginfo-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named tblib-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named sphinxcontrib_serializinghtml-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pytest_astropy-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named astroid-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Cython-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named webencodings-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named ply-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named partd-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named jsonschema-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named XlsxWriter-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named openpyxl-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named cloudpickle-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named navigator_updater-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named wcwidth-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named mistune-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named anaconda_client-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named isort-4
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named numpy-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named requests-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named idna-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pylint-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pyOpenSSL-19
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pyzmq-18
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named numba-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named mkl_fft-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named QtAwesome-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Send2Trash-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named Babel-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named conda-4
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pandas-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named traitlets-4
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named conda_verify-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named fsspec-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named scikit_image-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named singledispatch-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named simplegeneric-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named asn1crypto-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named cycler-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named soupsieve-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named six-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named parso-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named prometheus_client-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named QtPy-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named sphinxcontrib_jsmath-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named jedi-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named sphinxcontrib_websupport-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named nose-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named numexpr-2
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pyrsistent-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named astropy-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named numpydoc-0
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named pexpect-4
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named clyent-1
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named widgetsnbextension-3
WARNING: ImportError in sip recipe ignored: No module named sphinxcontrib_htmlhelp-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 838, in run
    self._run()
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1053, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1150, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1007, in process_recipes
    rval = check(self, mf)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/recipes/sip.py", line 116, in check
    mf.import_hook(pkg, m)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1082, in import_hook
    q, tail = self._find_head_package(parent, name, level)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1170, in _find_head_package
    q = self._import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1358, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1384, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1857, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1445, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(co, m)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1636, in _scan_code
    self._scan_ast(co, m)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1648, in _scan_ast
    imported_module = self._safe_import_hook(*args, **kwds)[0]
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1470, in _safe_import_hook
    mods = self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level, attr=attr)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1082, in import_hook
    q, tail = self._find_head_package(parent, name, level)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1170, in _find_head_package
    q = self._import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1358, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1384, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1857, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1445, in _load_module
    q = self._import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1358, in _import_module
    for field, value in iter_fields(node):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: It not clear if this is a problem with installing py2app, or with installing your own code that uses py2app. If it's the former, have you tried just installing [py2app](https://pypi.org/project/py2app/#description) using pip? E.g., with `pip install py2app`. It looks like your problem is that the required dependencies are not being installed when using `python setup.py py2app` - try also looking at the "Instal from source" section of the py2app documentation [here](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-from-source) if you really need to install from source.

Comment: It seems a lot of people are getting similar errors: Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136313/py2app-problems-getting-errors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985932/there-is-something-wrong-with-my-building-app-with-py2app?noredirect=1&lq=1). Two things I would try. First, try running in alias mode with `py2app setup.py py2app -A`. If that doesn't work, try what matt-pitkin suggests above.

Comment: @MattPitkin - Thanks for your response. The py2app is installed (and using the documentation you linked to). The issue is when trying to use py2app to create a stand-alone version of my own app. It doesn't matter what the app I try to create is, I always get that error.

Comment: @Yserbius - Thanks for the help. With Alias mode there is no issue, but the app won't run as it gives me an error that states '[the app] has encountered a fatal error, and will now terminate. A Python runtime not could be located [yes that spelling error is there] You may need to install a framework build of Python, or edit the PyRuntimeLocations array in this application's Info.plist file.' I previously came across the threads you mentioned, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the virtual environment created and creating a new one and again installing all the modules and creating the app. If you are not using a virtual environment try creating one it will work.